# using XPath to find node under a context node does not work (firefox/firebug/javascript)

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, xpath, firebug

I want to extract information from a web page.

The page has m nodes, which can be found by .evaluate("//div[@class='news']", document, ....).

For each of the above nodes, there are 3 nodes inside them. Each of them has different @class selector. And I want to extract these m 3-tuple records.

I tried to use .evaluate() function as instructed in

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript

by using this code

```
parentNodes = document.evaluate("//div[@class='news']", document, ....).
while (true){
   var node = parentNodes.iterateNext();
   var child = document.evaluate("//div[@class='title']", node, ....). 
   ...
}
```

However, "child" is always assigned to the first node in the document, instead of the first node within "node".

I ran this in firebug console.

Does any one know what's wrong?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are calling evaluate on the document. Hence, the XPath expression is being evaluated from the root of the XML tree. Also, if you want XPath to select a node from within the current context, e.g. among the children of the current node, you should use the `.//` context selector.

Comment: That "." in front was the key. Seems weird to me that you can specify a context, but still the path is relative to the root. Shrug.

Comment: @dbreaux it's just like in linux shell, `/bin/bash` points to the root dir no matter where you are, if you have another dir called bin in your current directory you have to do `./bin/bash` or `bin/bash`

Comment: How else can you call `evaluate` if not from `document` ?

Answer (score 6):

If you start an XPath expression with "/" then you are starting down from the root node/document node of the context node. So instead of `"//div[@class = 'title']"` use `"descendant::div[@class = 'title']"`, that way you are selecting the descendant div elements of the context node.

Comment: BTW `descendant::div[@class = 'title']` is equivalent to `.//div[@class = 'title']`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.//` instead of `//`.

Explanation from the [XML Path Language specification (XPath), Version 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev):

> - `//para` selects all the para descendants of the document root and thus selects all `para` elements in the same document as the context
>     node
> - `.` selects the context node
> - `.//para` selects the `para` element descendants of the context node

The current top answer is wrong in that there is no way to call `.evaluate` on any other object, but `document`. `document.evaluate` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also the [location path selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths) `descendant-or-self`. Like that: `descendant-or-self::div...` for reference starting the node passed as context.

I hope I have helped.